# Create read-only user on Collabnet Edge SVN

Tags: permissions, svn, read-only, collabnet

How can I create a read-only user (for access from another websvn server) on a Collabnet Edge SVN server?  I do have a level of administrative rights through the web interface as well as direct server access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen reference to a web interface that either isn't in 'my' version or I don't have access to for some reason.  In general, this seems to be handled by the `svn_access_file`.  It started as:

```
[/]
* = rw
```

I created a user named `readonly` and applied the [`~` operator](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).

```
[/]
* = r
~readonly = rw
```